# Call instance method by self.method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Having such object in Javascript

```
     SomeClass = {
        methodOne: function(){
            if ( SomeClass.methodTwo() ){
                     doSomething();
                 }
        },
        methodTwo: function(account){
           doSomethingElse()
        }
```

I want to call `self.methodTwo()` instead of `SomeClass.methodTwo()` in `methodOne` body, like it would be in Python.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use the word 'Class' in JavaScript, JS is a prototype based inheritance language, so you should write this this way:

```
var myPrototype = {
    methodOne: function () {
        console.log('Invoking method one');
        if (this.methodTwo()) {
            doSomething();
        }
    },
    methodTwo: function (account) {
        console.log('Inovking method two')
    }
}

var instance = Object.create(myPrototype);
```

You could use ES6 'class' syntactic sugar (and transpile it in ES5 for browser), sure, but I don't really like it (there is still no class in ES6, despite the new keywords).

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/d2hpaz0L/)

Comment: `this` returns me current HTML element, but not prototype

Comment: What? What HTML element?

Comment: @gena2 How are you calling methodOne? the context (`this`) may vary its value depending on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the second method via `this`:

```
var SomeClass = {
    methodOne: function(){
        if(this.methodTwo){
            console.log('first');
        }
    },
    methodTwo: function(){
        console.log('second');
    }
};
```

In this case, `this` refers to the object within which the function are declared.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
 SomeClass = function() {
        this.methodOne = function (){
            if ( this.methodTwo('') ){
                     doSomething();
                 }
        }
        this.methodTwo = function (account){
           doSomethingElse()
        }
    }

    var instance = new SomeClass();

    alert(instance.methodOne());
```